# ResourcesNotFoundException for ArrayList with Buttons

Tags: java, android, arraylist, scroll

I need do create an ArrayList fulled with buttons, which will be linked to Horizontal Scroll layout. I get a ResourceNotFound error when trying to change Button text, after inserting it into ArrayList:

```
public class Dictionary extends Activity implements Runnable, OnClickListener {
    //Candidates
    candidatesScrollView = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.activity_dictionary_horizontalScrollView1);

    candidatesButtons = new ArrayList<Button>();
    candidatesButtons.add((Button) findViewById(R.id.activity_dictionary_horizontalscrollview1_button1));
    candidatesButtons.add((Button) findViewById(R.id.activity_dictionary_horizontalscrollview1_button2));
    candidatesButtons.add((Button) findViewById(R.id.activity_dictionary_horizontalscrollview1_button3));
    candidatesButtons.add((Button) findViewById(R.id.activity_dictionary_horizontalscrollview1_button4));
    candidatesButtons.add((Button) findViewById(R.id.activity_dictionary_horizontalscrollview1_button5));
    candidatesButtons.add((Button) findViewById(R.id.activity_dictionary_horizontalscrollview1_button6));
    candidatesButtons.add((Button) findViewById(R.id.activity_dictionary_horizontalscrollview1_button7));
    candidatesButtons.add((Button) findViewById(R.id.activity_dictionary_horizontalscrollview1_button8));
    candidatesButtons.add((Button) findViewById(R.id.activity_dictionary_horizontalscrollview1_button9));
    candidatesButtons.add((Button) findViewById(R.id.activity_dictionary_horizontalscrollview1_button10));
    candidatesButtons.add((Button) findViewById(R.id.activity_dictionary_horizontalscrollview1_button11));
    candidatesButtons.add((Button) findViewById(R.id.activity_dictionary_horizontalscrollview1_button12));
    for(int i = 0; i < candidatesButtons.size(); i++)
        ((Button) candidatesButtons.get(i)).setOnClickListener(this);

    (...)
}
```

I try to change that property inside this method:

```
private void recognize() {

    (...)

    byte buffer[];
    buffer = RecogEngine.setResult(0); // and set the remaining data to engine
    try {
        candidatesString = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");     
        Button b;
        for (int i = 0; i < candidatesString.length(); i++)
            candidatesButtons.get(i).setText(candidatesString.charAt(i));
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    (...)
}
```

**What am I Doing wrong?**

Comment: I'm not very sure but there might be some confusion on java treating char and int, have not go through deep study tough, your code `candidatesButtons.get(i).setText(candidatesString.charAt(i));` may asks java to search for string resource object instead, try using `candidatesButtons.get(i).setText(String.valueOf(candidatesString.charAt(i)))`.

Comment: It works. If someone knows why previous solution was not working, I would be more than happy to know it! @Chor WaiChun you should explain more about this, and post it as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop to change button string uses candidatesString length as loop incrementor so if the length is more than 12 it will throw that exception because you only have 12 buttons.

I dont know the business logic you are trying to implement within that for loop. But the following code should work for 12 buttons. Or need to restrict the for loop for min (12 or candidatesString.length)

```
for (int i = 0; i < candidatesString.length(); i++)
            if(i < 12)
                candidatesButtons.get(i).setText(candidatesString.charAt(i));
    }
```

Comment: That is a good advice, but it is not the case of error. Please check the above.